# How to count text length with special characters?

Tags: javascript, string-length

For example, `const words = 'a̋b̋';`, the `words.length` is `4`. But we are expecting `2` for "real" length.

Or, is there any safe way to go through all the characters from this above `words`?

Comment: have a look https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode

Comment: Thanks for the reading

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing built into JavaScript that will help you differentiate those combining marks from other characters. You could build something, of course, using the reference information from http://unicode.org. :-)

...but at least one person seems to have already done so for you: https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter

> Enter the grapheme-splitter.js library. It can be used to properly split JavaScript strings into what a human user would call separate letters (or "extended grapheme clusters" in Unicode terminology), no matter what their internal representation is. It is an implementation of the Unicode UAX-29 standard.

```
const words = 'a̋b̋';
const splitter = new GraphemeSplitter();
const graphemes = splitter.splitGraphemes(words);
console.log(graphemes);
```

That results in two entries in `graphemes`, `"a̋"` and `"b̋"`. (Can't do live example, live links to github raw pages are disallowed.)